# Rails server: Fields can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm running my rails server, trying to sign up a user. I receive `'(field name)' can't be blank` error. When I create a User through the Rails console, I have no errors, but when I try to go through the server, the fields it says are blank (which aren't) are: `:first_name`, `:last_name`, `:email`, `:password`, and `:password_confirmation` (I'm entering all of these fields through the server).

I thought this might be an error pertaining to Devise, but I'm not so sure any more, because I switched my new user view over to Devise's registration view along with the complimentary routes.

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signup_params

def new
  @user = User.new
  render 'new'
end


def create
  @user = User.new(signup_params)
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def signup_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation     #tried removing this due to strong params, to no avail
validates_uniqueness_of :email
devise :database_authenticatable, :timeoutable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

before_save :create_session_token

def create_session_token
    self.session_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
end
```

Schema (for users):

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
t.string   "session_token"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
end
```

views/devise/registration/new:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<%= f.text_field :first_name ,placeholder: 'First Name',  class: 'signUpForm', id: 'firstName' %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name ,placeholder: 'Last Name',  class: 'signUpForm', id: 'lastName' %>
<%= f.email_field :email ,placeholder: 'Email',  class: 'signUpForm', id: 'email' %>
<%= f.password_field :password ,placeholder: 'Password',  class: 'signUpForm', id: 'password' %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation ,placeholder: 'Confirm Password',  class: 'signUpForm', id: 'confirm_password' %>

<%= f.submit class: 'signUpForm btn btn-inverse', id: 'submit'%>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

If anyone could share any advice as to why these fields are not being saved through the server, I'd be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Stacktrace:

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"4KvHBYLTXs+wRAyB/1d5DKRVRqWO3eFKWyFwlbQ+dSE=", "user"=>     {"first_name"=>"adfs", "last_name"=>"asdffasd", "email"=>"asdfsd@email.arizona.edu",     "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: email, password, password_confirmation

 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY '' LIMIT 1
 (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
 Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.8ms)
 Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (27.8ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 502ms (Views: 143.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

Updated errors:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-26 15:50:44 -0700
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4KvHBYLTXs+wRAyB/1d5DKRVRqWO3eFKWyFwlbQ+dSE=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"adfs", "last_name"=>"asdffasd", "email"=>"asdfsd@email.arizona.edu", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: email, password, password_confirmation, first_name, last_name
```

Comment: can you paste your stacktrace with the error?

Comment: Like `<%= form_for(@user, :as => @user, :url => registration_path(@user)) do |f| %>`? But where do I put the params?

Comment: Devise::RegistrationsController // Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name... You are posting to devise, that's where you should permit your fields... https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Do I actually have to put that inside the gem?

Comment: I edited those, but I'm recieving the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the error : "Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name"
You need to permit them for Devise Controller.
In the `ApplicationController` add this:

```
 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name << :last_name 
  end
```

**EDIT**

Also, remove the `protected_attributes` gem as it is conflicting with strong parameters.

Comment: @user3181113 Exact same error? Can you update your question with the error and the code that you updated in ApplicationController.